# Вытащить текст с помощью регулярок

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
[2018-11-09 18:29:19] [Output] : Бла-бла-бла Some_Nick что-то там сделал.
```

Необходимо с помощью регулярок вытащить "Some_nick", "Бла-бла-бла", "что-то там сделал".

P.S Текст "что-то там сделал" - может быть разный

"Бла-бла-бла" - статичный, никогда не меняется.

"Some_Nick" - может меняться.

Думаю, что можно как-то оттолкнуться от "[Output] : " - но вообще не понимаю, как это можно сделать с помощью регулярок.

Comment: Никак. В вопросе данных недостаточно.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте `^\[.+\] \[Output\] : Бла-бла-бла ([A-Za-z_]+) (.+)\.$`

Comment: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 133), match='[2018-11-09 18:29:19] [Output] : Бла-бла-бла So> - на выводе получаю это.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null Это такая шутка? Тег вопроса - C++, а в комментарии выходит, что на самом деле вы пишете код на Python? Добавьте ваш код в вопрос.